# If Γ is a closed Jordan curve that encloses a region with area A, show that $A=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{\Gamma} \overline{z}dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

If Γ is a closed Jordan curve that encloses a region with area A, show that  $A=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{\Gamma} \overline{z}dz$.
Then show that $A=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{\Gamma} \overline{z}dz$ can be written as $A=\frac{1}{4i}\int_{\Gamma}\overline{z}-z d\overline{z}$.

I have no clue where to start here.

Comment: *Hint.* Write $$ \int_{\Gamma} \bar{z} \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_{\Gamma} (x - iy) \, (\mathrm{d}x + i \mathrm{d}y) = \int_{\Gamma} ((x \, \mathrm{d}x + y \, \mathrm{d}y) + i(x \, \mathrm{d}y - y \, \mathrm{d}x) ) $$ and apply the Green's Theorem.

Comment: There is also the theorem $$\int_{\partial \Omega} f\:dz = 2i \iint\limits_\Omega^{} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\:dx\wedge dy$$ Also, you might be missing a $dz$ in the second integral so it reads $$\frac{1}{4i}\int_\Gamma \bar{z}\:dz - z\:d\bar{z}$$ which again follows from the theorem.